# Directing incoming requests based on port number

Tags: dns, php, web, minecraft

I am not sure how to describe my issue, but I will try to explain.

I have been hosting a personal Minecraft server from my PC. I then changed the DNS on one of my site's sub domains to my IP. It works fine and visitors can join the server with the URL. It used port 25565.

The thing is, I want to use the same url to now host a web page (PHP) with server stats, (in port 80).

In order to do this, I have to change the DNS back to my web server, which means users can not join the Minecraft server.

Is there a way that I can achieve this? - Show a webpage in sub.domin.com (port 80) while at the same time redirecting any requests for port 25565 to my IP?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to port forward in your firewall/router.  I guarantee you there's no shortage of guides and how-tos available for whatever gear you have.

And in regards to changing DNS -- why not just add another A record pointing to the same IP address?  For example, `www.yourdomain.com` and `minecraft.yourdomain.com` both pointing to the same IP.

Comment: Port forwarding already works. The issue it I am trying to use sub.domin.com for both port 80 and 25565 so that when visiting sub.domin.com from a web browser it shows the webpage but using sub.domin.com in minecraft connects to server.

Comment: So forward port 80 to webserver and 25565 to minecraft server . . .